# sending to an email with contact form asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How would I go about sending an email to a specified email address with a contact form in asp.net? The website is hosted though a hosting company. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("your.mail.server");

mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("to_address@mfc.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail";

SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Yup. That'll do it. :) Although, sometimes you may also need to add the port manually.

Comment: how would i find out my smtp credentials? and the smptClient server details?

Comment: Read the FAQ from the hosting company. If that information is not present, open a support ticket at your hosting company