# email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-development-serv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending to an email with contact form asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049088/sending-to-an-email-with-contact-form-asp-net)

How to send email from ASP.NET page using C# as for forget password, password will be automatically emailed to the alternate id. I need how is it possible to send email from ASP.NET page using C#.

Comment: Please don't email passwords. (You shouldn't even store them in plain text).

Comment: Well thanks everybody for your advice... But Am sorry to say that I just mean an example.. Of course to send an automated mail... Or to email some value of textbox may be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send an email in a .NET application.

Answer (score 3):

There is no shortage of articles and [tutorials](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) on this.

Side note: Being able to email the user their password implies that you're storing their password in plain text.  Please, *please* don't do that.  Passwords should be stored in an encrypted form.  If the user forgets their password, email them a temporary link for them to reset their password.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting sounds like a security risk. It is inadvisable to send a password through email, since this assumes your are storing the plain text password somewhere. Since you should only know the salted hash of the password, you probably want to make the user reset their password instead.

I suppose if you still have some reason to send an email you can check out an extensive tutorial [here](http://systemwebmail.com/) to start. Seriously though, You can compromise all of your users security if you are not hashing there passwords, and even more so if you are emailing them out.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, as stated above (+1'd btw), to use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.

However, it's dangerous to go emailing passwords around. As a rule of thumb:

- Don't **send** passwords in clear text
- Don't **store** passwords in clear text

When storing a password (if you don't have some framework that does all this for you)

- Create a salt
- Append the salt to the password
- Hash the resulting string
- Store the salt and resulting hash
- Discard the password
- When authenticating, add the salt to
  the newly provided password, hash the
  resulting string, and compare to your
  stored hash

If a user has forgotten their password, send that user an email containing a one-time use, time-sensitive (expires in 1 hour?), unique-link to reset his/her password. It's also a good practice to require the user to manually provide his/her account name or other identifying criteria on the password-reset form.

Comment: Also how to set password to expire in next 1 hour?